# What is the difference when calling tokio::spawn with and without async block?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

In [this Tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning), it has the code:

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
    process(socket).await;
});
```

I can't figure out why `async move {}` block is used here. To my understanding so far it is unnecessary. The following works just fine and is more concise and direct:

```
tokio::spawn(process(socket));
```

So, my questions are

1. Is the `async` block necessary in this code?
2. If so, what difference does it make?
3. Without compiler optimization, wouldn't the `async` block add an extra layer of indirection, likely to cause a tiny-bit of drop in the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is the async block necessary in this code?

Most of the time, no; but see the next answer.

> 2. If so, what difference does it make?

In case `process()` is defined as `async fn`, nothing. Some people prefer one form, but this is subjective.

However, if `process()` is defined as  a regular function that returns a `Future`, there is a difference: with an `async` block, *all* of `process()` is executed in the newly spawned task, while without it, the call to `process()` is executed in the parent task, and only the future it returns is executed in the spawned task.

This can be important, if, for example, the future that `process()` returns is not `'static` (or `Send`), in which case the call without the `async` block will fail. Or if `process()` itself may be expensive, and we want it to execute in another task, and not just the future it returns.

As a note, there is a similar distinction when calling [`Runtime::block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on), but there the distinction is even more important: without `async` block, the code in `process()` executes *outside of the async runtime*. That means that calls to functions that require an active runtime (e.g. `tokio::spawn()`) will fail.

> 3. Without compiler optimization, wouldn't the async block add an extra layer of indirection, likely to cause a tiny-bit of drop in the performance?

I don't know the exact implementation details of generators (and async functions and blocks, which are implemented on top of generators), but this is unlikely. Async blocks in Rust don't allocate, and I don't think that using an `async` block that only forwards will incur any overhead.

Comment: Hi Chayim, thanks for the response. So, if process is an async function, then spawn(process()) / block_on(process()) is equivalent to spawn(async { process().await }) / block_on(async { process().await }). However, if process is a regular function that returns a Future, then the two makes a difference. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: @techhara Yes, it is. There is not necessarily a difference: it may be that all the function does is returning the future and it does not do any work on its own, and even if it does, it may not be important if it is executed in the task or in the parent. But yes, there may be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ChayimFriedman's [answer](/a/76763917/2189130), the `move` part of the `async move {}` may be important.

Not necessarily in the code shown, but in a similar case where the `async` function is expecting a reference the `move` might be required in order to sculpt a `Future` that has ownership.

Here's a demonstration that the direct approach triggers a lifetime error while the `async` block doesn't due to the `move`:

```
async fn process(_: &i32) {}

fn main() {
    let n = 5;
    
    tokio::spawn(process(&n));
    
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        process(&n).await
    });
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `n` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:6:26
   |
4  |     let n = 5;
   |         - binding `n` declared here
5  |     
6  |     tokio::spawn(process(&n));
   |                  --------^^-
   |                  |       |
   |                  |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                  argument requires that `n` is borrowed for `'static`
...
11 | }
   | - `n` dropped here while still borrowed
```